# I need to access backend models from a frontend controller in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using Yii 2 framework. How can I access my backend models from my frontend controller. I tried the code below.

```
$tnc = new \app\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions();
```

But I got this error

```
Class 'app\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since namespace for backend is `backend`, you should simply try :

```
$tnc = \backend\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions();
```

> In the Advanced Application Template, each tier has its own root alias. For example, the front-end tier has a root alias `@frontend`, while the back-end tier root alias is `@backend`. As a result, you may put the front-end classes under the namespace `frontend` while the back-end classes are under `backend`. This will allow these classes to be autoloaded by the Yii autoloader.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html